# Нужны ли запятые перед «и»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, и

Не уверен с запятыми в двух предложениях.

1. В карете много тел(,) и все они усыплены какой-то пахучей отравой.
2. Ни одно не шевелилось(,) и все казались давным-давно почившими на свет иной.

Comment: Джин. Не игнорируйте, пожалуйста, замечания на счет стрелочек и галочек. Вам вскоре просто перестанут отвечать. Не хотите играть по таким правилам – задавайте свои вопросы на других платформах.

Answer (score 1):

Ваши предложения мне кажутся не совсем удачными.

**I.** *В карете много тел(,) и все они усыплены какой-то пахучей отравой.*

Слово [**тело**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE) имеет много значений, и ни одно из них к нашей ситуации не подходит, так как *пахучая отрава* попадает внутрь путем *вдыхания* и только потом усыпляет кого-то (если насмерть, то и "получается" тело).
2. Организм человека или животного в его внешних физических формах и проявлениях.
4. Останки умершего человека; мёртвый человек, труп.

Вместо "тела" можно использовать другие слова: *люди, пассажиры, попутчики, путешественники, путники* (в зависимости от контекста).

Возможные варианты:
В карете много тел — все пассажиры были усыплены какой-то пахучей отравой. [о мертвых]
В карете много людей, и все они усыплены какой-то пахучей отравой. [о спящих]

Перед "и" я бы поставила запятую, не считая "в карете" общим второстепенным членом.

[Запятая в сложносочиненном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133)

**II.** *Ни одно не шевелилось, и все казались давным-давно почившими на свет иной.*

Две основы в предложении (*ни одно* [тело] *не шевелилось* и *все казались*), поэтому ставим запятую перед "и" на общих основаниях.

За щитами больше ничего не шевелилось, и пехотные французские солдаты с офицерами пошли к воротам. [Л. Н. Толстой. Война и мир. Том третий (1867-1869)]

[Почивший](http://endic.ru/word_stress/Pochivshij-24948.html) — тот, кто умер, покойный.
"Почивший на свет иной" = ***умерший** на свет иной*. Так нельзя говорить, сочетание "на свет иной" здесь лишнее.
Можно написать так:
казались давным-давно почившими (умершими, неживыми, мертвыми);
казались давным-давно ушедшими в мир иной (покинувшими этот мир).